# selectdatewidget set default month and day

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

How can I set selectDateWidget day and month options to default as 1st January but leave the year option intact.

Now I am doing:

```
day = datetime.date.today()
lessTime = forms.DateField(required=False, widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2013)), initial=day)
```

But this sets the default to the actual date. What can I change to give me the desired default options?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom widget e.g `MySelectDateWidget`

```
class MySelectDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        from collections import namedtuple
        date_tweak = namedtuple('Date', 'year month day')
        date_value = date_tweak(None, 1, 1) #tweak to cheat SelectDateWidget's 
                                   #render method which expects a datetime object
        return super(MySelectDateWidget, self).render(name, date_value, attrs)
```

and then replace:

```
lessTime = forms.DateField(required=False,    
          widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2013)), initial=day)
```

with:

```
lessTime = forms.DateField(required=False,          
                           widget=MySelectDateWidget(years=range(1980, 2013)))
```

Comment: This works great in setting the default options but now my Django form says it isn't valid after submission.
     form = ContactForm(request.POST)
     form.is_vaild() 
>>> form == False
What can I change to make this work?

Comment: 2020: if you are using Django 3 (or perhaps a later version of 2) the `render` methods in `MySelectDateWidget/1` should both be `renderer`.